# Missing parametrize variable in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I have

```
class Transform2Test(TestCase):
    @pytest.mark.parametrize('x', ['transform', 'preview'])
    def test_get_start_and_end_date_non_passed(self, x):
        a = 1
```

but I receive the error:

> E                   TypeError: test_get_start_and_end_date_non_passed() missing 1 required positional arguments: 'x'

I'm not sure why it doesn't pass the variable. This happens when running pytest on the CLI and inside pycharm.

Comment: You seem to mix `unittest` and `pytest` here. Using `parametrize` in a `unittest.TestCase` does not work - if you want to use it do not derive your test class from `TestCase`.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen thanks, but I thought pytest could safely use unittest's tests?

Comment: Yes, but not the other way around. If you derive from `unittest.TestCase`, that will handle the arguments and will choke on the additional `x` it does not understand.